# Concatenate two vectors and store the result

Tags: rust

I code in Rust, but one doesn't need to be familiar with Rust to understand the question.

We are given the two vectors, *first* and *res*. Our goal is to append *res* to *first*, and then to assign the result to *res*.

Let's consider the following two approaches. The first one is

```rust
first.extend(res);
res = first;
```

The second one is

```rust
res = first.into_iter().chain(res.into_iter()).collect();
```

The former seems to be more readable, but the latter is somewhat more straightforward: "take *first*, turn it into the iterator, chain it with the iterator obtained from consuming *res*, then collect the result". Also, there is only one line of code instead of two.

I would prefer the first one. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you want:

```
res = [first, rest].concat(); // require your type to be cloneable
```

Or:

```
res.splice(0..0, first);
```

Or:

```
res = vec![first, rest].into_iter().flatten().collect();
```

But it seems odd that you are assembling the `Vec` this way. Usually we try to assemble it from beginning to end. I'd look to see if there is a better way to structure to code to avoid this.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try using `res = [first, res].concat();` a compiler tells me that "the trait `Clone` is not implemented", but `splice` looks like what is needed. Thank you.

Comment: @memoryallocator, hmm.., the concat method doesn't seem to require cloneability, so I'm not sure why it didn't work.

Comment: As I understand, that's because `[first, res]` requires cloneability. `vec![first, res]` works, though, but I would like to avoid the unnecessary construction of a vector.

Comment: @memoryallocator, `vec!` doesn't work when I test it. It looks to me like `concat` does actually require `Clone`, although its it a bit roundabout since it goes through an unstable `Concat` trait.